# Windbg Cant get values of locals

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

Iam using Windbg to debug my .net application and loading SOS.dll.
After set breakpoint and hit it using command "P" to step into code.
Every time a use command "P" I use also Command "!CLRStack -a" to get value or address of parameters and locals but local still  all the time . I hope anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the watch window for autos and locals show anything when you are stepping through? You can also dump the local variables using command: `dv`

Answer (score -1):

You will not get the local variable values if you are using release build.
To have this facility, you should be analyzing the debug build or have private symbols for your appplication

Comment: First thank you for your reply. Iam using debug build and try again and also got the same result I can got values of argument but can not get values of locals as follow :   002becd0 004e0149 ConsoleApplication1.Test.Test1(System.String)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = 0x01e28b58
        rep = 0x01e28b38
    LOCALS:
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>

using command "p" to go to next line and still Locals equal <no data>